# Avoiding duplicate data & calculations in view-models

Tags: apache-flex, mvvm, viewmodel

I'm working on a Flex application that uses MVVM. I understand that it's recommended to have a 1-to-1 mapping between views and view-models. How then do I avoid performing the same calculations and storing the same data multiple times if it is needed in multiple views?

For example, imagine I have a program that can load project files consisting of a list of items. The main tab of my application has an export button that should only be enabled if the project is valid so I create an `isExportEnabled` property on the view-model for the main tab. The calculation for this involves validating the project by iterating though every item in the project and verifying some attribute on each. I have another tab which has a "Print Project Summary" button so the view-model for this tab has `isPrintEnabled`. The value for this flag is based on the same criteria, whether or not the project is valid.

1. I could put the logic for determining these values in their respective view-models, but then I end up calculating the same value twice when a project is loaded.
2. I could move `isValid` to the domain model but then the model becomes denormalized. What if a saved project is edited without updating the "isValid" flag?
3. I could make a global "Project View-Model" for the entire project which calculates whether the project is valid and then have `isExportEnabled` and `isPrintEnabled` delegate to that. However, then I end up with a hierarchy of view-models which this article recommends avoiding: [Applying the Presentation Model in Flex](http://blogs.adobe.com/tomsugden/2009/08/applying_the_presentation_mode.html)

It feels like there is no correct way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

So you are saying you have two user gestures, "Export" and "Print Project Summary" which are based on the same validation function ?  If I read your post right then you can calculate it once and have two getters

```
private var _isValid:Boolean;
public function validate():Boolean
{
    _isValid = //result of calculation
    dispatchEvent( new Event("isValidChange") )
}
[Bindable(Event="isValidChange")]
public function get canExport():Boolean
{
   return _isValid;
}
[Bindable(Event="isValidChange")]
public function get canPrint():Boolean
{
   return _isValid;
}
```

Now some may say that since they are returning the same value that we should get rid of the getters and return a simple [Bindable] public value.  But since this seems like the first implementation of this feature, having two separate functions allows you some robustness in the face of changing UI and validation requirements.

Personally, if the validation logic got too heavy, I would keep that value on my model "public var isValidProject" since the model should know if it is valid or not.  Then the presentation layer would use that value to determine how to represent to the user that this is an invalid project (popups,alerts,error strings ).

In other cases, I would make a setter on the presenter of those buttons "set selectedProject" and run my validation and/or change my buttons enablement state there.

I would really be interested to hear others thoughts on this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I rewrote some of the question since it wasn't as clear as I thought upon 2nd reading.